# Android TabLayout tabGravity ignored

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm trying to keep tabs on the left corner, but without scrolling. For some reason, in all modes, except scrolling, tabGravity is ignored: with fixed or auto tabMode tabs is displaying on the center. Is there are some third setting in the tabLayout, or just bug inside TabLayout itself?